# NSOutlineView + XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

Just getting into NSOutlineViews and see them a useful control.

Is it possible to show a **Xib** as the **root item**??

Fritzables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys......     Good news.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you use a view based `NSOutlineView`. First register the nib you want to display for a cell using [registerNib:forIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/registerNib%3aforIdentifier%3a) (`windowDidLoad` in a window controller would be a good place, awakeFromNib is also  a possibility).

```
NSNib *cellNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
[self.outlineView registerNib:cellNib forIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
```

Next in your `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` you get a (possibly recycled) instance of your nib by using the earlier specified identifier:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    NSView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" owner:self];

    // optional configuration here

    return cellView;
}
```

I've got a [blog post + mac app sample code](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/01/03/nib-based-table-views/) that demonstrates this.

Comment: When I use the above code, I see the following error:

No visible @interface for 'NSOutlineView' declares the selector 'makeViewWithIdentifier:ownder:'

Where to now??

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. Just updated my answer. I was referring to [makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW23) (docs). (`owner:` instead of `ownder:`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just have to switch it to use view based cells.

In your delegate, implement `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` to provide the correct XIB.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is Possible, `NSOutlineView` is another great visual control available in **Mac OS X**. Being descendant of the NSTableView It represents the hierarchical data. You can collapse and expand nodes, see parents and their children. In this article we will describe how to use NSOutlineView to show DASchema object which by its nature is a good example of the tree-like data.

For more info check [Here](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Displaying_Data_in_NSOutlineView)